# Bootstrap dropdown binding using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to knockoutjs so I really need some advice how to accomplish this requirement. In my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trn9z8tL/3/), I have link with dynamic displaying of data in modal. I'm using this to populate the data in dropdown

```
var eventViewModel = function() {
  var me = this,
    eventTypes = [{
      cls: 'fa fa-fw fa-globe',
      label: 'Create Public Venue',
      text: 'Visible to anyone',
      url: "Link-to-Public"
    }, {
      cls: 'fa fa-fw fa-lock',
      label: 'Create Private Venue',
      text: 'Visible only to people invited',
      url: "Link-to-Private"
    }];

  //ko.cleanNode($('#add-event-modal .dropdown-menu')[0]); //ongoing
  // How to clear the dropdown value (in actual solution the values are repeating everytime the modal called)

  me.EventForm = new viewModel();

  me.eventTypes = ko.observableArray(eventTypes);
  me.change = function(type, event) {
    alert('Changed');
    //Changing body content
    //event.preventDefault();
    //var elem = $(".modal-body");
    //transitionToNewContent(elem, type.url);
  }
};
```

I have three questions:

1. I'm trying to bind the bootstrap dropdown to the header but I don't know how to do it using bootstrap dropdown. The selected item should display depending on the selected data and disable the selected value or add higlight and icon `fa-check`. I tried researching but to no avail, I can't seem to understand at all.
2. In my solution, the validation is working but in jsfiddle it seems that it's not working. My problem with regards to this is how to display the error with bootstrap error.

`ko.validation.init({
  errorElementClass: 'has-error',
  errorMessageClass: 'help-block',
  decorateInputElement: true
});`

I tried using the above code but again, to no avail it's not displaying the bootstrap error color.

3. Lastly, how to clear the `me.eventTypes` observablearray? In my solution, every time I call the modal the dropdown values are repeating. (Sorry I can't replicate it to jsfiddle)

Any help and/or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's a few issues with the post as-is making it hard to answer. First, the post itself should contain a *minimal* repro (the jsfiddle one is.... big). Second, I'd suggest asking only one isolated question at a time (I understand sometimes "sub" questions should be asked in one, but here, not so sure...). Finally, for any question, specifically your 3rd: if you cannot create a minimal repro, then we don't *have* a repro, and it's impossible for us to validate our answers before posting.

Comment: One important note on the actual question: I see your comment on `ko.cleanNode`. You ask "how to clear the dropdown value?", but with KnockoutJS you should typically modify the *viewmodel*, not the *DOM*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to (hopefully...) answer the first and third question; the second one doesn't seem to be an issue if it's only the fiddle that isn't working.

**Question 1:**

First, you'll need an extra observable in your viewmodel to keep track of the selected type. You can set this type inside your `change` method which is already correctly implemented.

```
me.selectedType = ko.observable(eventTypes[0]);

me.change = function(type, event) {
  me.selectedType(type);
};
```

Now, we can bind the `<button>` element to this `selectedType`, rather than hardcoding the text and icon:

```
<button 
  class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" 
  type="button" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" 
  data-bind="with:selectedType"> 

  <span data-bind="attr: {class: cls}"></span>
  <!-- ko text: label --><!-- /ko -->
  <span class="caret"></span>

</button>
```

Notice the `with` data-bind, which is very similar to the `foreach` you've used in your `<ul>`.

Now, if you want to style your `<li>`s differently for the currently selected element, you can check if they're selected like so:

```
$parent.selectedType() === $data
```

For example:

```
<li data-bind="style: { opacity: $parent.selectedType() === $data ? 0.5 : 1 }">
```

(It's probably better to create a computed observable `isSelected` and add it to your `type` objects)

I've included these changes in a fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLm3yvLh/ (Note that you still might to move some stuff around; I haven't read nor touched most parts of your code)

**Question 3:**

It's kind of hard for me to guess what's wrong, but you can clear an observable array in roughly two ways:

1. Set it with a new, empty array: `myObservableArray([])`
2. Remove all items from the currently set array: `myObservableArray.removeAll()`